# How to get list of files from .wim file

Tags: python

I came across a problem that I can't get a list of files from a file with a .wim extension

I need something like this:

```py
path = 'path/to/folder/example.wim'
with ZipFile(path, 'r') as zip_obj:
   list_of_iles = zip_obj.namelist()
```

But it works only with .zip files

Comment: `.vim` or `.wim` because one is a text file containing the configuration for a `vim` editor, the other one is a disk image file...

Comment: Question only makes sense if it's `.wim`. @OP: It makes sense that this wouldn't work with WIM files, as they're not zip files. You'll have to find (or write) a Python library that can understand their structure.

Comment: Sorry, I mean .wim extension

Comment: try to look here https://github.com/0xGiddi/python-wimlib